# `std::bitset::reference` assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, assignment-operator, bitset

I was reading the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference) of `std::bitset::reference`, and I am not sure to understand why, there are two assignment operators defined:

```
reference& operator=( bool x );
reference& operator=( const reference& x );
```

Are the two declarations for optimization reasons, or because the compiler-generated copy function would not have the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical proxy reference class stores a pointer (or reference) to the `bitset` and the index of the bit referred to (or something equivalent to these). A memberwise copy assignment, if it compiles, would in all likelihood simply reseat the "reference".

But you want `b[0] = b[1]` to assign the *value* of the second bit to the first bit, rather than reseat the proxy reference returned by `b[0]` to refer to the second bit. Hence the need for the second overload.